# Add static value to PDO result row

Tags: php, arrays, select, pdo, append

I want to add a statically declared element (`saved_id`) to the row data populated by a database query result.

This is my code:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM wishlists WHERE user_id='1'");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$res = array('saved_id' => "1");
array_push($result, $res);
echo json_encode($result);
```

Current result:

```
[{"id":"1","user_id":"1","name":"San Francisco","privacy":"0","pick":"Yes"},{"saved_id":"1"}]
```

Desired result:

```
[{"id":"1","user_id":"1","name":"San Francisco","privacy":"0","pick":"Yes","saved_id":"1"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
array_push($result, $res);
```

To

```
$result = array_map( function($r) use($res){
    return array_merge($r, $res);
}, $result);
```

Answer (score 4):

In case multiple results are expected, it would be simpler to inject the desired value *right in the query*:

```
$saved_id = 1;
$user_id = 1;
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT *, ? as saved_id FROM wishlists WHERE user_id=?");
$stmt->execute([$saved_id, $user_id]);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($result);
```

But if you need only one row, you have to use `fetch()` instead of `fetchAll()`
and in this case you can add whatever elements to the fetched row later:

```
$user_id = 1;
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM wishlists WHERE user_id=?");
$stmt->execute([$user_id]);
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$result['saved_id'] = "1";
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$result['saved_id'] = "1"; working but fetchAll not working :( i want fetchAll

Comment: There was a silly typo in my code, I fixed it. Always have error_reporting(E_ALL) so you'll be able to fix at least such trifle issues yourself

Comment: $stmt->execute([$saved_id, $user_id]); is problem not show error reporting this HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: then you are using outdated PHP version,

Comment: your second snippet is the most uncomplicated, plain and smooth way to add another element to the array in a loop, it is so simple that the majority just forget how easy it is. The simplest solution are always the best!

Comment: @deepcell thank you, though there is no loop in the second snippet :)

Comment: @YourCommonSense yes I know ;D .. I expressed wrongly, I am using it in a foreach, to push additional data into the new query results.